# Does Python have iocp support?

Tags: python, python-3.4, iocp

While stumbling upon the newly introduced [selectors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) module, I was wondering why all the major I/O waiting mechanisms are available but iocp.
Is there somewhere a plugin with iocp functionality?

Comment: Maybe [ProactorEventLoop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) in [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html)

Comment: @PaulRooney Id like to have a solution in which I'm not bound to anything  (like asyncio => which cant be used in conjunction with normal threads). But you are right that one could probably take ProactorEventLoop and isolate the iocp part from asyncio. I don't get why this wasnt done similar to the selectors module,